# How to append data to a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, httprequest

I have my code below that shows the data from an api into a collection view. what i want to know is how to append data that status is equal to like we say " completed" i only want to show names on collectionview which status is equal to "completed" Thanks. or for example status = "created".

sample api raw data:

```
         {
            "id": 72,
            "name": "fsd",
            "desc": "fdsfsdf",
            "reward": "1.00",
            "sched": "2018-04-07T18:46:35.643713+08:00",
            "parent": "sfsd",
            "child": "fsdfdsf",
            "occurrence": {
                "name": "once"
            },
            "status": {
                "name": "created"
            },
            "date_created": "2018-04-09T21:15:16.263911+08:00",
            "date_modified": "2018-04-09T21:15:16.291715+08:00"
        }
```

code for getting from the api

```
func demoApi() {
        Alamofire.request("http://test.test:test/api/v1/chores/", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {


            case .success(_):
                guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}
                print("Response \(json)")
                for item in json {

                    self.getAllDetail.append(item

                }
                if !self.getAllDetail.isEmpty{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                break

            case .failure(_):
                print("Error")
                break

            }
        }

    }
```

code for collection view -

```
var getAllDetail: [[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]]()

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return getAllDetail.count
        }


        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
            if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row] {
            cell.nameLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as? String  ?? "" //titleArray[indexPath.row]
              }
            return cell
        }



        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            // handle tap events
            print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
            if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row] {
               print("You selected ID #\( getTempDetails["userId"] as? String  ?? "" )!")
        }

        }
```

Comment: what is the exact problem you are facing in this code?

Comment: i want to only to show data name which status is equal to created

Comment: cell.nameLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as? String  ?? " , iwant that cell.name.label.text =  getTempDetails["name"] as? String  ?? "  which status is equal to created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
        if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row] {
            if let str = getTempDetails["status"] as? [String, String] {
                  if let name == str["name"] as? String{
                       if name == "created"{

                       cell.nameLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as! String

                   }else {
                       cell.nameLabel.text = @"Uncreated"

                    }
                }
             }
          }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: does the code stated above could be able to detect if this name has this status?

Comment: yes try it. if it still gives error than let me know error msg.

Comment: there is a problem with your code , what i actually want Sir is that the name of data that i want to load is data which status is equal to created and not name == created , as you have seen in the api above there is name and status

Comment: i think your code is just identifying if name value is equal to created

Comment: Show name which status is created not name value

Comment: for example   "name": "fsd", and the status of fsd is  "status": {
            "name": "created"
        }, so i fsd will show because hes status is  = created

Comment: check it now. if still need change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168573/discussion-between-durn-kurvirck-and-mrizwan33).

Comment: may be casting error you should try casting values.

Comment: lets continue on chat